TabView navigation stuck in tvOS
I’m implementing a carousel view for tvOS. In its simplest version, it would be:
struct HorizontalCarouselComponent: View {

    let contents: [ContentViewModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(contents) { content in
                Text(content.title)
                    .focusable(true)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}

With this version, I can see the content correctly and also the pagination. However, when I navigate using the arrow keys on the Apple TV simulator, I notice that some elements of the carousel become unreachable. For example, I can move two positions to the right, and even though there are two more positions, I cannot continue moving forward.
I have tried using TabView with selection or setting the focus manually with @FocusState and focused, but none of them seem to work. What I expect is to reach every position of the pagination using the arrow keys or the remote.
Do you have any ideas on what might be happening?
Should I go for ScrollView and forget about TabView?

It seems to be a problem with the simulator. The same code works perfectly on a physical device.
